# All IPs which are connecting to Middle, except the IPs in consensus file are Bridges?

Tags: bridge, middle

All IPs which are connecting to Middle Realy, except the IPs in the consensus file are Bridge IPs?

Are there any other IPs possible?

Answer (score 0):

The Tor network does not make any distinction about "middle" relays, so I'm assuming you mean a relay without the *Guard* or *Exit* flags.

In most cases incoming connections will be from guard or bridge relays, but not always. A Tor client is allowed to build circuits through any relays it wants in any order, so a Tor client may connect directly to a "middle" relay. Directory authorities may also connect directly to the relay in order to check if it's up. If the relay is acting as a directory cache, people may also download directory documents from the relay's DirPort. I'm not sure if there are others.

Comment: Thanks Steve for the answer! I agree that DAs may also connect to the "middle relay" (not Guard or Exit). If the relay's DirPort is not configured and only OR port is open, downloading docs also may not be possible. Also, i think, a Tor Client can not built a circuit with "middle relay" if its not having a Guard flag as the first node. Hence, may i assume, the IPs reaching to "middle relay (not Guard or Exit)" are either bridges or DAs? Please correct me if i am wrong!

Comment: ssvasu: Tor clients won't connect directly by default if you don't have the guard flag, but that doesn't mean they can't, either by changing torrc settings (for example `UseEntryGuards 0`), or using custom path selection with [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html#stem.control.Controller.new_circuit).